# Lost appCache by Android 4.4 WebView

Tags: android, webview, chromium, android-4.4-kitkat, html5-appcache

I'm developing **android 4.4** application using WebView of Chromium base.
It lost to the appCache when the process is Kill. (Ex. task list, settings - application - stop)

android 4.3 or lower is no problem.

1. app start on Online
2. launch WebView activity                 <- get appCache
3. app start on OffLine
4. launch WebView activity using appCache  <- no problem
5. Kill Process from task list
6. app start on OffLine
7. launch WebView activity <- **cannot using
   appcache. lost appcache!**

How to workaround this problem?

Thanks,

tmk

---

**Update 16, Mar**

I detected following message in chromium. Probably, AppCache has been cleanup by the chromium.

> [ERROR:cache_creator.cc(115)] Unable to create cache
>
> [ERROR:appcache_storage_impl.cc(1803)] Failed to open the appcache
>   diskcache.

---

I found it to occur only over https(SSL).

Comment: Is this related to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64620 ?

Comment: Thank you comments. I'm investigating whether there is a workaround.